# Is there a version of NeoJSON that works in Pharo 1.1?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

Is there a version of NeoJSON that works in Pharo 1.1?  If so, how do I access this version?  Is there a better place or way to ask this question, other than StackOverflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NeoJSON is newer than Pharo 1.1, so there probably is no version designated for it. What happens if you just try loading the newest version? The pharo users mailing list is the right place for this kind of question. If it does not load, it is easiest to load the latest version in the latest Pharo, and make a version that can load in Pharo 1.1 there